# Error al instalar flask-mysql

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, flask

[image: Error]

Soy nuevo usando python3 y deseo que me ayuden ya que al insertar el comando `sudo pip3 install flask-mysqldb` ocurre el siguiente error

Comment: Tienes instalado el paquete libmysqlclient?

Comment: @EugeniBejan tengo instalado Xampp !!

Comment: Prueba con instalar estos paquetes. apt-get install  libmysqlclient-dev python-dev

Comment: Muchas gracias @EugeniBejan lo resolví  con tu ayuda!!

Answer (score 2):

La solución ya esta, pero publico la respuesta por si a alguien más le pasa lo mismo.

Este error suele ser muy típico el los sistemas Linux y la solución a ello es instalando unos paquetes

El comando para instalar los paquetes.

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python-dev
```